# Will this Android example be safe to use, memory leak-wise?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-fragments

When reading up on Fragments, I came across this section on [communicating with the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity), which contains the following snippet of code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

Somehow I have the feeling that fragments shouldn't contain a reference to their `Activity`, but I don't really know where this intuition comes from.

I feel like the code above can cause a memory leak when `setRetainInstance()` is set to `true`, because the `Activity` may restart on orientation change while the `Fragment` is retained, containing a reference to the old `Activity`. (Is this true?)

But will this pattern be safe to use with `setRetainInstance()` set to `false`?

Comment: Why not just call  ((OnArticleSelectedListener)getActivity()).listenerMethod() when you need it instead of holding a reference to it?

Comment: Because this is the example code in the Android dev guides! And you'll possibly get a `NullPoinerException` after the Fragment is detached, which I guess my question boils down to! Can you assume that a Fragment will not be detached from its activity as long as you may call the callback method? -- You have to take special care with `AsyncTasks` and such.

Comment: And so should you set `mListener` back to `null` in `onDetach()`?

Comment: Where are you calling your callbacks?

Comment: My app, specifically, in an `onClick` listener for `ListView` items, but my question is meant generally.

Comment: Well, in that case it'd be safe to assume getActivity() will exist since a ListView isn't going to be clickable / visible if the fragment isn't attached to an activity

Comment: In the case of things like async tasks you do need to do safety checks to make sure that calls to getActivity() aren't null since the tasks can outlive fragments or they can complete while rotating / not attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Somehow I have the feeling that fragments shouldn't contain a reference to their Activity,

They already do. Otherwise, the `getActivity()` method could not work.

> I feel like the code above can cause a memory leak when setRetainInstance() is set to true, because the Activity may restart on orientation change while the Fragment is retained, containing a reference to the old Activity. (Is this true?)

`onAttach()` will be called again, for the new activity, so while you will very briefly leak memory, I would not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the pointer in the on detach method.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    mListener = null;
}
```